# How to reload UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have an UIView Graph with main method and some other methods which draw various things. When the application starts, view is drawn fine and I have no problem with it. But when I try to use button (located on same UIView) to redraw something I just get error:

```
CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

button is not calling main drawRect method. Also if I try to use:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

I get error:

No visible @interface for viewcontroller declares the selector 'setNeedsDisplay'

Comment: `[self.view setneedsDisplay:YES];`

Comment: Are you storing the context with a strong pointer or regetting the context each time? Please show some code.

Comment: I am not storing context at all.

Comment: `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` no arguments for UIView.

Comment: Can you show your actual drawing code and anywhere you are accessing your `CGContextRef`

Answer (score 5):

`setNeedsDisplay` will not work for the subviews....it will work only for the View of a viewController

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method

```
- (void)setNeedsLayout
```

[setNeedsLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/setNeedsLayout) from developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the `UIViewController` instance whereas you need to call it on its `UIView`.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Comment: even if put my view name I get same error:

[self.GraphView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

[GraphView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

Comment: @JamesDouglas Is `GraphView` an instance? camelCase notation... ;)

Comment: GraphView is the actual view name on the stroyboard, and I used class name as well.

Comment: @JamesDouglas And so it's not a view...it's a storyboard

Comment: meaning what? it draws the stuff first time. My GraphView is subcluss of UIView and I happend to have same view name on storyboard